# How to get all parents changeset in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

Currently I am struggling with the Mercurial (v. 2.6.2) log feature. For creation of a change log of our software I have to collect the following set of changeset:

```
|
O A First interested revision on default
|
O B start of branch
|\  
| \
|  O C Commit on branch
O  | D commit on default
| /
|/
O E Merge from branch to default
|
|
O F start of release branch
|\
| \
O  | G on-going development on default
|  O H Patch fix on release branch
|  |
```

So what I try to get is a collection of changeset that contain A,(B),(C),D,E,(F),H.
The changesets in brackets would not harm if they are part of the log, but they would not be necessary. The changeset G must not be part of the log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ hg help revsets
$ hg log -r A::H
```

Comment: Many thanks. That was the solution! I always used A::head() which as I now learned means all heads for this branch. So after changing it to A:heads(<current release branch>) it worked.